# Creating a filtered list in Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, list

All,
I have in the order of 200k contacts that are synchronised into Salesforce Marketing Cloud from Salesforce CRM.

I want to send an email to a limited subset based on a bunch of filter parameters (created date, location, blah blah blah).

I hear people talking about Lists but I can't find where to put in filter conditions that bring people from the synchronised list across.

I know I am being dense, but I cannot see where to do this.  I need to operate exclusively within Marketing Cloud.

Thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Synchronized data from Sales Cloud falls into what are called `Synchronized Data Extensions`.  You can find that in either Email Studio > Subscribers or with the Contact Builder.

What you're likely trying to do is create a `filtered data extension` from the source data extension.

The other option is to use Automation Studio to create a Query Activity that will allow you to filter that way.

ADD:
Sample query image.  You must reference field names from source data extensions that you want to show in your target data extension.
[image]

Comment: Tom, Progress!  I have worked out how to create a filtered Data Extension.  Thanks!  As an extension to that.  Can I take two synced Data Extensions in Marketing Cloud and combine them together based on a key value?  If so, then I could create my filtered Data Extension on that (and that would be 10x more useful :) )

Comment: Yes. You'll need to use an automation studio query activity to do so.   This is a sql query.  It will look something like: SELECT a.fieldname, a.fieldname2, b.fieldname FROM ENT.[dataextension1] a  INNER JOIN ENT.[dataextension2] b ON a.fieldname = b.fieldname

Comment: Tom, I go to Automation Studio and create a query.  I get to the point of writing SQL and I see both Data Extensions and Salesforce Data Extensions, but not Synchronised Data Extensions.  Hence I can't create a query referring to them (or am I still being dense).  Cheers Jo

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Tom, and as en extension of above - the synchronised tables aren't in either of the other two data extension folders in the query window.

Comment: For query activities you need to create at destination data extension. You do not select source data extensions but rather use the sql query to reference one or many data extensions.   So first create a destination data extension with the fields you need from each of the 2 data extension you want to merge. Then write your query

Comment: Tom, so I create a DE with SFMC (Done).  How the heck do I get it to populate from the Synched DE?  Grrr.. I always feel like it is one step forward, two steps back - but I appreciate the help so much.  Slowly the steps forward are getting bigger and the steps back smaller :)

Comment: That's where you use the query.

Comment: But I can't reference the synched DE in the query... so how do I get the data from the synched DE to the local DE so I can use the local DE in the query?   I'll have a play and see what more falls out LOL

Comment: What do you mean, you can't reference the synched data extension?  Look up query activity on the marketing cloud help page for a quick look at how this works.

Comment: I am creating a query activity.  Nothing shows up in the salesforce data extensions section - so I can't see how I can reference data in there to then push it into a local DE.  This is my big confusion!